# If statement - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

How could I write this in an 'if statement' so if there is content it will post, otherwise it will not output anything?

**Code Edited:**
Now the problem is that it won't output with the *p tag*, just the text.

```
<?php
```

`$desc = $custom_metabox->the_value('description');`

`if (!empty($desc)): ?>`

`<p class="description"><?php echo $desc; ?></p>`

`<?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

PHP allows you to "exit" parsing inside of blocks... just make sure you get the braces properly matched up:

```
<?php if($whatYouWantToExist) { ?>
    <p class="description"><?php
    // usually needed
    global $custom_metabox;
    // get the meta data for the current post
    $custom_metabox->the_meta();
    // get value directly
    $custom_metabox->the_value('description'); 
    ?></p >
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I really appreciate this. One question, do I need the '$whatYouWantToExist' part?

Comment: @ChristopherBurton no, replace that with whatever condition you want.

Comment: You should replace that with what you want to exist. I haven't worked in WP in a long time... I don't recall how to check if there is post content, but however you do it, that's where you put it.

Comment: Perhaps `!empty($post->post_content)` is the check you are looking for; I'm not sure.

Comment: Hmm. I have very very little knowledge of PHP. There's no easier way to just say 'if has content --> post, else do nothing?

Comment: Perhaps `<?php if($post->post_content) { ?>` is what you are after. Note that in my posted code, just replace `$whatYouWantToExist` with `$post->post_content`